# How did I get +3 rep for an upvote after I hit the 200 rep cap for today? Did the rules change?

Tags: support, reputation

I now have 218 rep on EL&U from today, 15 of which is from an accepted answer.  What I'm wondering is, how did I get 203 rep in one day?

Comment: (I'm perfectly happy for things to be this way, but I'm curious.)

Comment: OK, now I've just gotten upvoted on an answer, and got no rep.  How am I missing 3 rep that is not counted toward the rep cap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FAQ reports the following text:

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions. You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although **accepted answers** and bounty awards are immune to this limit). Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate reputation.

*Accepted answers* is referring to both your answers, accepted by who asked the question, and the answers that you accepted.
You accepted two answers, which would give you 4 points; you probably down-voted an answer, and that would take you to 3 points beyond the limit of 200. Add your answers which were accepted, and you go to 233.